# error: Unknown module(s) in QT: phonon

Tags: qt, qt-creator, phonon

I am beginner with Qt.
I installed Qt creator in Windows 7.
When I write `Qt += phonon` in `project.pro`, I meet with this error:

```
error: Unknown module(s) in QT: phonon
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score -1):

On Windows you should compile phonon module by yourself, it required directx sdk.
You can read about building phonon in this [article](http://rain87workbook.blogspot.ru/2010/10/building-vlc-phonon-backend-under.html)

Comment: if my answer help you, please click accept, else post your correct answer and select